# Is there a way to squish the panel in a pie chart ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried many theme but somehow can't get it to squish my pie chart as I want in the panel.

I added an `element_rect()` to show which part I want to squish.

Let me know if you have useful resources on squishing a ggplot. I have difficulty grasping what can be changed.

`legend.box.spacing = unit(-20, "pt")` appears to be the closest to what I want.

If there was some kind of `panel.margin` parameter, it would be great?

Or maybe axis still take-up space and that would be a ggplot2 bug?

```r
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(
  category = c("A", "B", "C"),
  value = c(30, 45, 25)
)
mg_equal <- function(x) {
  margin(x, x, x, x)
}
ggplot(data, aes(x = 1, y = value, fill = category)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", clip = "on") +
  labs(title = "Pie Chart Example") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
     panel.background = element_rect(),
    # plot.margin =mg_equal(-50). # doesn't really do what I want
    # panel.
    # #legend.box.spacing = unit(-20, "pt"),
    # panel.grid = element_blank()
  )  # Position the legend at the bottom
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "squish the panel"?

Comment: I just mean the the panel.background would just take-up less space. the square would be closer to the actual plot.

Comment: Adding `scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0.5, 1.4), oob = scales::oob_keep) +` will bring it closer, but not all the way.

Comment: @JonSpring Thanks so much. It worked well enough to reduce most of the whitespace.